# Various Relationship in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server and Entity Framework.

Suppose I have 2 tables named `tblOfficeAccessType` and `tblOfficeAccessDepartment`. I introduce them in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCOYk.jpg).

I put some data in tables as instance. In `tblOfficeAccessType` we have the access codes to office and in `tblOfficeAccessDepartment` we have various departments of office. we want that the User could define various access levels for each `AccessCode`. For example The User could define the [`AccessCode = AQ1`] allows to access to the `Manager_Room` but It does not allow to access to the `Store`. Note that various offices have various departments and various Users have Various selections. How do that?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblOfficeAccessDepartment] 
(
     [DepartmentId]   VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
     [DepartmentName] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DepartmentId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblOfficeAccessType] 
(
     [AccessId]   VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
     [AccessCode] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AccessId] ASC)
);
```

Update :

I want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzIJ2.jpg)

Comment: What did you tried before?

Comment: @Vahid Farahmandian What do you mean?

Comment: Could you show the expected result?

Comment: @alex Yes, Of Course. I edited my question. please see that.

Comment: Ok, so you need a 3rd table with departmentId, AccessId, and IsAllowed. what's the problem?

Comment: @Zohar Peled thanks, but with this manner we have to repeat the `AccessCode` column.

Comment: No, you don't. you need to repeat AccessId.